# Curve fitting with Matlab fails miserably

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit a curve in Matlab using `fit` in command line. The input data is:

```
X =

     1
     2
     4
     5
     8
     9
    10
    13

Y =

1.0e-04 *

    0.1994
    0.0733
    0.0255
    0.0169
    0.0077
    0.0051
    0.0042
    0.0027
```

And the target function is

```
Y = 1/(kappa*X.^a)
```

I am using `fittype`, `fitoptions`, and `fit` as follow:

```
model1 = fittype('1/(kappa*x.^pow)');
opt1 = fitoptions(model1);
opt1.StartPoint = [1e-5 -2];
[fit1,gof1] = fit(X,Y.^-1,model1,opt1)
```

I get results with `rsquare` of roughly -450 which are vaguely in the same direction as the measurement.[image: I have attached a figure to demonstrate this]. How can I improve Matlab fitting skills?

*Edit*:

I removed the `.^-1` in the fit command. This improved the behavior but it is not entirely correct. If I set model1 to be:

```
model1 = fittype('1/(kappa*x.^pow)');
```

The fit is bad. If I set it to be:

```
model1 = fittype('kappa*x.^pow');
```

The fit is good (with kappa being a very small number and pow being negative).

I have also normalized `Y` and I get a reasonable results

Comment: is the ^-1 in `fit` intended?

Answer (score 6):

You should replace

```
[fit1,gof1] = fit(X,Y.^-1,model1,opt1)
```

by

```
[fit1,gof1] = fit(X,Y,model1,opt1)
```

Also your initial condition for `kappa` is `1e-5`, which would make sense if `kappa` was in the numerator.

Using the model `kappa*x.^pow`, with the initial condition `[1e-5 -2]`, you would get the right fit:

```
X =[1     2     4     5     8     9    10    13]';
Y = 1.0e-04 * [0.1994 0.0733 0.0255 0.0169 0.0077 0.0051 0.0042  0.0027]';

model1 = fittype('kappa*x.^pow');
opt1 = fitoptions(model1);
opt1.StartPoint = [1e-5 -2];
[fit1,gof1] = fit(X,Y,model1,opt1)
plot(fit1, X, Y)
```

The fitted result is

```
>> fit1
fit1 = 
   General model:
   fit1(x) = kappa*x.^pow
   Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
     kappa =   2.044e-05  (1.931e-05, 2.158e-05)
     pow =      -1.657  (-1.851, -1.464)
```

[image: Fitted Curve]